# Copy with Batch

Tags: batch-file

Hey guys ok so I'm trying to merge some files and if possible keep the folders and sub folder

the file I used for testing is called (1) Austin.txt

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 

For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 1") Do Set "source=%%~fG"
For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 2") Do Set "target=%%~fG"
For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 3") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%source%\*.txt"') DO call :label "%%q"
goto :eof

:Label
set "FILE=%~1"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "appi"^<"%~1"') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "opcn"^<"%~1"') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%~1"') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%target%\%~n1A.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "paid"^<"%~1" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "whbn"^<"%~1" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%~1" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%target%\%~n1B.txt"

If Exist "%target%\*.txt" If Exist "%destdir%\" (
        Copy /Y /B "%target%\(1) AustinA.txt" + "%target%\(1) AustinB.txt" "%destdir%\(1).txt"
    )
```

OK so up to this point my results will look like this

```
Source New Folder 1
    | City
        | (1) Austin.txt
Target New Folder 2
    | (1) AustinA.txt
    | (1) AustinB.txt
```

Now on this section on my original script it would merge A.txt and B.txt to (1).txt 
now that I have the original file name, I am not sure how to merge Target to (1) Austin.txt

This is no longer needed

```
If Exist "%target%\*.txt" If Exist "%destdir%\" (
    Copy /Y /B "%target%\(1) AustinA.txt" + "%target%\(1) AustinB.txt" "%destdir%\?????????"
)
```

I need A and B to be merged with the original name of the file

```
    Source New Folder 1
        | City
            | (1) Austin.txt
    Target New Folder 2
        | City
            | (1) AustinA.txt
            | (1) AustinB.txt
    Destdir New Folder 3
       | City
           | (1) Austin.txt
```

Here is what changed Now my script 99% perfect adding the second `>` is all I needed to do, for weeks I have been looking for a way to merge my files

From this

```
)>"%target%\%~n1A.txt"
)>"%target%\%~n1B.txt"
```

To this

```
)>"%target%\%~n1.txt"
)>>"%target%\%~n1.txt"
```

and I removed this

```
For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 3") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"
```

This extraction can read between codes in any readable files 
This extraction can be cut in half, if you only need to extract between 2 codes

my setup reads for codes and put them in one .txt file

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 

For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 1") Do Set "source=%%~fG"
For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 2") Do Set "target=%%~fG"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%source%\*.txt"') DO call :label "%%q"
goto :eof

:Label
set "FILE=%~1"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "CODE1"^<"%~1"') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "CODE2"^<"%~1"') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%~1"') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%target%\%~n1.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "CODE3"^<"%~1" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "CODE4"^<"%~1" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%~1" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>>"%target%\%~n1.txt"
```

RESULTS

```
Source New Folder 1
        | City Folder
            | (1) Austin.txt
    Target New Folder 2  < ---- missing City Folder
        | (1) Austin.txt
```

Still working on folders

Thank You Stephan for the wonderful help

Comment: Honestly I suggest you do this in powershell.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid in my original script, in batch it works great, but in order for it to work I have to enter the file's name into my batch, and I get my results, and It can edit 30 files in 10 seconds,  I have over 5000, so you can see why I'm looking for help with the last few steps, do you know how to keep the folders, I know `%~nx1` keeps filename and extension, how do I keep the folders, and sub folders

Comment: Everyone has their preferred languages. I stopped using batch a long time ago because Powershell is so much more superior from a maintenance and debugging perspective. Like batch, it's windows native and can be edited in notepad. and if you want you can simply write batch inside your powershell.... and if you like you can easily do windows UI's. Perhaps you could put a clearer example of what you're after and someone who loves batch will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("%~1") do for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do echo "%%~nxb\%%~nxa"
```

where `%~1` is a fully qualified filename (`X:\Some Folder\Folder 1\file.ext`). Output: `"Folder 1\file.ext"` (last folder plus filename plus extension)

But why do you generate two files, just to join them? Just put both outputs into the same file:

```
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%~1"') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%destdir%\%~nx1"
...
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%~1" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>>"%destdir%\%~nx1"
```

Comment: @Stephen Um, didn't think that was possible, because when I first started, the second part overwrites the first part, that is why I kept it into 2 files, since it has the same name, I did figure out how to work the `%~nx1, I did Google how to copy folders and subfolders, but no luck Thanks

Comment: `>` to overwrite, `>>` to append (see [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)). To copy folders, use `xcopy` or `robocopy` (where did you try to copy folders?)

Comment: in my script you will see I have a copy `/y /B', never tried >>

Comment: I also tried xcopy, with a different setup, but it took 2 minutes per file, and working with over 5000 files, x 2 minutes I'll end up watching my baby girl graduate high school, @Stephan Thank you once I get home from work, I'll test

Comment: I'm trying to get the folders and sub folders to transfer over with the files as well, not sure if my script will be able to do that, were `New folder 1 City Folder is also in New Folder 2`

Comment: Still not quite sure what you try to accomplish. To copy an entire "branch" (recursively with files and folders), `xcopy /s "sourcefolder\*" "destinationfolder\"` or `xcopy /e ...` (depends on what you want). See `xcopy /?` for more info.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the `tree of folder and subfolders` at the same time as the files are being edited, if you look at my question the last part, you will see that target is missing the folder `City` if  put `5 folders in Source`, it puts them in target, but `with out folders`, so I would end up with 100 edited .txt files with no folders, so then what I do is highlight files cut and paste back to the original folder found in source, I was literally testing `robocopy and xcopy`, when I saw your message, when I tested those I was getting weird results

Comment: I would like to Thank you for all the help, I have learned a lot and now understand a lot, I am no longer looking to making my script copy `Folders and Sub Folders` as my files get edited, would be great to learn that, but I recently learned something new, that helped with my goal, and this will help me in the future for other projects.